# How to design following dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How is following dialog box designed, sorry But I am no gui developer but with some initial help I can do this. What I want is `tree view` is attached to `right pane` and how it change with selection in the `tree view` and the `lower text` also change with each selection.

[image]

Any starting point would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify. How would your application show a VS property sheet at the client site?

Comment: I would like to launch such dialog box from a visual studio add-in for example If I create Visual Studio integration package then I want to call this dialog box from private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Do you want to know how to *design* (as in, what controls to use) such a dialog?

Comment: @Cicada : Yes I want to know what Controls are used, I figured out that left pane is tree control , but I am not sure about right pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure guessing so maybe it's not entirely correct:

[image: Layout]

Pardon the cheesy colors, I don't know why I did this...

Comment: Thank you very much, If you have more details on the same and could share on how to design would be great help to me.

Comment: Well uh, I don't see what else to add? You pretty much have the entire blueprint of the design with this picture.

Comment: How to add properites in the Propertygrid, Like on Tree View I see add nodes and all but on proptygrid there is nothing

Comment: It works by selecting an object to work on. Here it's certainly a configuration object. I'll let you [check the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Again, but it is not allowed me to select a tree node